# Get actual location google maps v2 ANDROID

Tags: android, google-maps, location

I want to get the current position with a GoogleMap object, I'm doing that like this:

```
private void setUpMap() {
mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        final Location location = mMap.getMyLocation();
        Log.w("status", "yes");

        if (location != null) {
            Log.w("status", "no");
            latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),
                    location.getLongitude());
        }
        mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMyLocationChange(Location loc) {
                loc = location;
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, MAP_ZOOM));
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude())).title("It's Me!"));
            }
        });
    }
```

I don't know if I have to use another tool to get the current position, because location is always null.
Of course the second log is never showing.

Answer (score 0):

according to [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/location) you have to use [location api](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html) .instead of using getMyLocation or you can say MyLocatonLayer use [LocationApi](http://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html) . and getMyLocation is [Deprecated](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#getMyLocation%28%29).

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to try it.